# Ember.js CollectionView strange behavior

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, collectionview

I am trying to create autocomplete behavior with emberjs. I am observing in the controller an input field (`searchCity`) and making ajax calls according to that field. I have a view which handles additional logic, and should display a list of clickable cities as suggestions. So far I have the following code:

```
var labelView = Ember.View.extend({
                templateName: 'searchedCities',
                geoData: null,
                click:function(){
                    debugger;
                }
            }),
    ModalView = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'modal_layout',
    cities: null,
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.cities = Ember.CollectionView.create({
                tagName: 'span',
                itemViewClass: labelView
        });
    },
    cityList: function(){

        var callback,
            cities = this.get('cities'),
            searchCity = this.get('controller').get('searchCity'),
            regExp = new RegExp(searchCity, 'i');

        if (!searchCity){
            return;
        }
        callback = function(data){
            var aux = data.filter(function(geoObjects){
                return geoObjects.city.match(regExp);
            }).slice(0,9);

            cities.clear();
            aux.forEach(function(geoData){
                cities.pushObject(labelView.create({geoData:geoData}));
            });
        };
        Store.resolveGeoData(callback);
    }.property('controller.searchCity')
});
```

In my template I have the following code:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=searchCity placeholder="City"}}

             {{#each view.cities}}
                {{this.geoData.city}}
            {{/each}}

            {{#each view.cityList}}
                {{this.city}}
            {{/each}}
```

Even though in the callback I can check that the cities are populated with the views in my template nothing is shown if i remove the `{{#each view.cityList}}{{/each}}`, but it displays if I leave it there.

Comment: do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: no errors in the console